# How to programmatically change jquerymobile page and send data to this page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

guys!
I use jquerymobile 1.3.0 and jquery 1.9.1
I have 2(more) jquerymobile pages.
For example:

```
<div data-role="page" id="firstPage">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div data-role="header">
        <h3>First page</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- Body -->
    <div data-role="content">
        some content ...
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="secondPage">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div data-role="header">
        <h3>Second page</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- Body -->
    <div data-role="content">
        some content ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm need to change from first page to second page, and send some params usually URL
I tried to use this method:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#secondPage',
    {
        data: {id: 123, module: 111}
    }
);
```

After this method, the elements on first page is hide and url is change to
 `www.mydomain.com/main.html?id=123&module=111`
but page is not change. I think in order to change the page to a URL to a hash of this page.
and the URL must be of the form

```
www.mydomain.com/main.html?id=123&module=111#secondPage
```

then i tried to use:

```
location.href += '?id=1234&module=111#secondPage';
```

This method is work )))
But when i tried go back to firstPage, page is changed, but in URL remain the data

```
www.mydomain.com/main.html?id=123&module=111
```

Then i tried delete this data using next method

```
location.href = location.href.replace(location.origin, "").replace(location.pathname, "");
```

But after this method my firstPage is looped to change.
Please help guys. How to send data to secondPage and delete this data when i going back to firstPage? 
My back button used native jquerymobile method for go back.

```
<a data-theme="a" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" href="#firstPage" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left backButton"></a>
```

P/S. I'm sorry for my english, my english level is elementary

Answer (score 1):

If you define two pages in one html, you don't have to send arguments to other page with URL. Just use javascript variables and page events to use them.

If you use URL arguments to run server side code, just use different .html files. One html file, one page style.

But for smooth transition effects on mobile devices and best user experiment, i prefer using AJAX and create/change pages live,

Best regards

Comment: Hello!
Yes, of course! At the moment, I keep all the parameters in JavaScript variables, but after refreshing the page all the parameters are lost. I need to save the settings in the url in order to restore them after refresh the page